# How to load a url in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `div` in which I have to load external url. 
I already used jQuery load function.

I am using js file of jQuery with proper syntax. I don't want use Iframe.

code:-

```
<div id="content"><div>
```

jQuery:-

```
$('#content').load(http://www.google.com);
```

Please suggest me advice.

Comment: `$('#content').load(http://www.google.com);` - missig id selector `#`

Comment: Also note that this will be subjected to Same Origin Policy constrains... meaning you may not be able to load contents from a different origin(domian)

Comment: Google the following terms: jQuery selectors, iFrame, same origin policy and XSS attacks... that would be my advice. Oh, and _"QUOTE"_ the url, it's a string!

Comment: I want to load url using cross domain .

Answer (score -1):

You're not targeting the div. Try

```
$('#content').load('http://www.google.com');
```

Also, that's just a direct method of loading it. If you want to do something with the data, try the .get or .post (depending on your needs) functions. It's slightly beyond the scope of your question, but it's useful to know about

```
$.get('page.php', function(data)
{
    //You can do something with data here
    $("#content").html(data);
});
```

Post

```
$.post('post.php', { query: "Search Term" }, function(data)
{
    //You can do something with data here
    $("#content").html(data);
});
```

JSON

```
$.getJSON('json.php', function(data)
{
    //Assuming your return has a name attribute
    $("#content").html(data.name);
});
```

Comment: You can't load something from another domain, due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: I know it's not universal, but doesn't JS now allow for cross-domain requests?

Comment: Have you tried loading the content from local scripts? As pointed out by Archer you're not actually going to be able to load Google. Though cross-domain requests are possible now, you have to set it up on the server side to allow it. So does your problem come from trying to load an external website or from the code?